# SSH disable port forward remotely instead of killing process on the server

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, remote-access

I am making an automatic remote SSH port forward request from my device every few minutes:

```
ssh -y -f -N -R port:localhost:22 user@server \
-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=60 \
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

If the port forwarding is successful and I reboot my device and reset internet connection, I am unable to connect to it or make new port forwarding (this is normal and ok as my IP is changed and the port seems to be occupied). I have to wait about 1-2 hours so that the port is free again or I need to kill the process on my server.

I would like to send a script from my device before turning it off that would free the port, so that after reboot new port forward request is successful.

To summarize: How can I remotely cancel port forwarding from the device that requested it, instead of killing the process on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Use these `sshd` options on the server (in `sshd_config` file):

```
ClientAliveCountMax 3
ClientAliveInterval 15
```

---

#### Client-side story

> How can I remotely cancel port forwarding from the device that requested it, instead of killing the process on the server?

The simple answer is: just terminate the `ssh` on the client. Even if you force-kill it, the server should be notified the connection is terminated (because [it's the kernel that does the job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438146)).

**…if the notification ever gets to the server, that is.** I guess this is the problem. Networking on your device somehow drops before `ssh` is terminated and there is no way to notify the server this particular SSH connection is no more.

Maybe you can redesign your client-side setup to ensure `ssh` terminates before anything is done to the network connection. I don't know the details of your client-side system, so I won't tell you exactly what you can do and how. Loose examples: `systemd` units and their dependencies, if applicable; a wrapper over `reboot` and/or `shutdown`.

---

#### Server-side story

I assume the SSH server is standard `sshd`. Its default config (`sshd_config`) specifies

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

From [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> `TCPKeepAlive`
>
> Specifies whether the system should send TCP keepalive messages to the other side. If they are sent, death of the connection or crash of one of the machines will be properly noticed. However, this means that connections will die if the route is down temporarily, and some people find it annoying. On the other hand, if TCP keepalives are not sent, sessions may hang indefinitely on the server, leaving ''ghost'' users and consuming server resources.
>
> The default is `yes` (to send TCP keepalive messages), and the server will notice if the network goes down or the client host crashes. This avoids infinitely hanging sessions.

This mechanism is not specific to SSH. Explanation:

> In Linux, TCP keepalive parameters are:
>
> `tcp_keepalive_intvl`
>   `tcp_keepalive_probes`
>   `tcp_keepalive_time`
>
> Their default values are:
>
> `tcp_keepalive_time = 7200` (seconds)
>   `tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75` (seconds)
>   `tcp_keepalive_probes = 9` (number of probes)
>
> This means that the keepalive process waits for two hours (7200 secs) for socket activity before sending the first keepalive probe, and then resend it every 75 seconds. If no `ACK` response is received for nine consecutive times, the connection is marked as broken.

([Source](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000044970)).

This explains why you "have to wait about 1-2 hours so that the port is free again".

Examples of how you can change these values (if you have the permissions):

- temporarily

  ```
  echo 300 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
  ```

  or

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
  ```
- permanently by editing the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, add:

  ```
  net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
  ```

  then invoke `sudo sysctl -p` to apply the change.

**But** these are system-wide settings. In general any change will affect more than `sshd`. That's why it's better to use SSH-specific solution. Again from [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> `ClientAliveCountMax`
>
> Sets the number of client alive messages (see below) which may be sent without `sshd(8)` receiving any messages back from the client. If this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, `sshd` will disconnect the client, terminating the session. It is important to note that the use of client alive messages is very different from `TCPKeepAlive`. […] The client alive mechanism is valuable when the client or server depend on knowing when a connection has become inactive.
>
> The default value is `3`. If `ClientAliveInterval` (see below) is set to `15`, and `ClientAliveCountMax` is left at the default, unresponsive SSH clients will be disconnected after approximately 45 seconds. This option applies to protocol version 2 only.
>
> `ClientAliveInterval`
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, `sshd(8)` will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is `0`, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client. This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

**If only you can reconfigure `sshd` on the server, this is in my opinion the most elegant way.** Let the `sshd_config` contain lines like:

```
ClientAliveCountMax 3
ClientAliveInterval 15
```

Notes:

- `-o ServerAliveInterval=60` you use is a similar option for `ssh`; it allows the client to detect broken connection. It doesn't affect the server though.
- you may consider [`autossh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) on the client.

---

#### Back to the client

Let's suppose you cannot reconfigure the server nor the client. I know you said

> instead of killing the process on the server

but in this case killing it may be the best option. As `sshd` forks to serve particular connections, it's enough to kill just the right process without affecting the rest. To initiate killing from the client, you should modify the way you invoke `ssh`. You said:

> every few minutes:
>
> ```
> ssh -f …
> ```

Instead of this, you may run a script similar to the following one, just once (e.g. via `@reboot` in crontab). It tries to kill the saved PID (of `sshd`, on the server) first, then establish a tunnel and save its `sshd` PID. If the tunnel cannot be established or gets terminated eventually, the script sleeps a while and loops.

```
#!/bin/sh
port=12345
address=user@server
while :; do
  ssh $address '[ -f ~/.tunnel.pid ] && kill `cat ~/.tunnel.pid` && rm ~/.tunnel.pid'
  ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R ${port}:localhost:22 $address 'echo $PPID > ~/.tunnel.pid; exec sleep infinity'
  sleep 60
done
```

Notes:

- This is quick and dirty script, a proof of concept; portability was not my priority.
- For clarity I've omitted some options you originally used.
- If you run the script twice, the two instances will kill each other's tunnels over and over again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will terminate shh on client-side before rebooting. I didn't know that server will be noticed about that.

Additionally I will modify sshd config on server.

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding can be canceled using the `ssh` escape character (`~` at the beginning of a line, by default) or `~?` for help

```
Supported escape sequences:
 ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
 ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
 ~C   - open a command line
 ~R   - request rekey
 ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
 ~^Z  - suspend ssh
 ~#   - list forwarded connections
 ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
 ~?   - this message
 ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

and `~#` will list connections but not really in a way suitable for killing them via a command

```
The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)
```

which can be found via `~C` and then `help`

```
ssh> help
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -D[bind_address:]port                  Request dynamic forward
      -KL[bind_address:]port                 Cancel local forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward
      -KD[bind_address:]port                 Cancel dynamic forward
```

so in theory yours could be canceled via `~C-KL22` to open the command line and cancel the `LocalForward` by port number.

Whether this will solve your issue is unclear; ports usually take far less than 1-2 hours to clear `TIME_WAIT` or such...